# URL to create a new Google document

Tags: google-docs

What is the current URL to create a new Google Document please?
Since Google last updated their Docs the old URL does not work.

Comment: [This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150644/117311) which shows how to even build a **custom shortcut for creating a new file** may also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can create a new doc, spreadsheet, presentation or drawing via the following URLs:

- https://docs.google.com/document/create
- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create
- https://docs.google.com/presentation/create
- https://docs.google.com/drawings/create

If you're using the paid version of Google Apps, the URLs need to include your domain name:

- https://docs.google.com/a/your.domain.com/document/create
- https://docs.google.com/a/your.domain.com/spreadsheets/create
- https://docs.google.com/a/your.domain.com/presentation/create
- https://docs.google.com/a/your.domain.com/drawings/create

(Correct as of Feb 2018, but liable to change.)

Comment: How to make it creating google document in specific folder of google drive?

Comment: Is there a URL parameter to create a doc using a specific template?

Comment: To make create a Google Document in a specific folder, see this [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89069/113117)

Comment: @kolo The URL to create a new Google Drive Spreadsheet has changed to : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create

Answer (score 20):

Here are some easier-to-remember and faster-to-type links for creating new Google Docs. As of Nov 5, 2018, these all work.

- [doc.new](http://doc.new), [docs.new](http://docs.new), [document.new](http://document.new), or [docs.google.com/create](http://docs.google.com/create)
- [sheet.new](http://sheet.new), [sheets.new](http://sheets.new), [spreadsheet.new](http://spreadsheet.new), or [sheets.google.com/create](http://sheets.google.com/create)
- [slide.new](http://slide.new), [slides.new](http://slides.new), [deck.new](http://deck.new), [presentation.new](http://presentation.new), or [slides.google.com/create](http://slides.google.com/create)
- [form.new](http://form.new), [forms.new](http://forms.new), or [forms.google.com/create](http://forms.google.com/create)
- [site.new](http://site.new), [sites.new](http://sites.new), [website.new](http://website.new), or [sites.google.com/create](http://sites.google.com/create)
- [drawings.google.com/create](http://drawings.google.com/create)

Note that if you are signed in to Google with multiple accounts (say, personal and work in the same browser), it might not ask you which account you would like to use and may immediately create a document under your first account.

Comment: If you're using Google Apps for Business, the URL is slightly different: `https://docs.google.com/a/your.domain.com/document/create`

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a document with a given document name:

https://docs.google.com/document/create?title=YOUR_TITLE

Comment: any way to provide the body?

Comment: see also: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/117748/18716

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Links are now broken.

> I realize that this question is as old as the original answer is
>   outdated.  The new URL for document creation is
>   https://drive.google.com/document/create, likewise with other new
>   Drive-related files.

Comment: The `docs.google` isn't outdated, it still works.

Answer (score 2):

[There is now](https://twitter.com/googledocs/status/1055490445088903168) a fancy new way: the `.new` [gTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain).

Per [QZ](https://qz.com/work/1441913/a-new-trick-for-starting-google-docs-slides-sheets-and-forms/), all these URLs now work:

- Docs: doc.new, docs.new, document.new
- Forms: form.new, forms.new
- Sheets: sheet.new, sheets.new, spreadsheet.new
- Sites: site.new, sites.new, website.new
- Slides: slides.new, deck.new, presentation.new