# Craft URL to create Google Doc in specific folder?

Tags: google-drive, url

After searching, the closest information I've found is [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26304/url-to-create-a-new-google-document). However, that answer covers just creating a Google Drive file, period. I would like to find out how to make that file get created in a specific folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I watched what happens when Google Docs creates a new document in a folder. The browser briefly goes to a create url. To make the url, you need to know your folder's id. If you navigate to the folder in a browser, its id is at the end of the url:

```
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/[string_of_characters_is_the_folder_id]
```

Copy the id, open a new browser tab, and paste the id onto the end of the create url, like so:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/create?usp=drive_web&folder=[string_of_characters_is_the_folder_id]
```

Press Enter, and the browser will go to your new document created in the folder identified in the url.

Comment: Next step in this journey is to create a file FROM A TEMPLATE and have it created INSIDE OF A SPECIFIC FOLDER... once that is complete I will attain cosmic awareness... lol. Thank you so much...

Comment: Is it fair to say that a document using a template is essentially a copy of a certain document? I mean I don't see a difference between a template-based document and a copy-based document.

Comment: Mind. Blown. Of course. Thank you. Now I can generate templated work forms for my co-workers and provide links from Trello that will generate copies in the folders where they need to go... this is perfection.

Comment: randomblink, I want what you describe, but I can't make the leap from jaycer's hint to your insight. How do you construct a URL that creates a new copy-based document that goes to a particular folder?

Comment: Agreed, has anyone managed to figure out what the command is?

Comment: This didn't work for me. Is it possible it doesn't work on G Suite accounts or it doesn't work for shared folders?

Comment: @jml and midasmax I've added an answer [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/139589/15308) that shows how to craft a URL which creates a Google Doc from a template and puts it in a specific folder.

Comment: @katriel I can confirm it works in a G Suite folder that is shared with people.

Answer (score 9):

I know this thread has been quiet for a while, but it helped me.

I was able to accomplish this by:

1. getting the URL of the destination folder `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/[Folder ID]`
2. taking the file's url
3. replacing `/edit` with `/copy`
4. adding the `copyDestination` param to the end

*Original URL:*

`https://docs.google.com/[specific file URL]/edit`

*Final result would look like this:*

`https://docs.google.com/[specific file URL]/copy?copyDestination=[Folder ID]`

I hope this helps!

Comment: shame I can only upvote this answer once

Comment: Is this still working for people? I'm getting Not Found Error 404.

Comment: It still works.

Comment: hm, the urls made with this now work for me on files I created/folders I own, but not for other accounts. It copies the file, but not into the folder and so it isn't shared (all files and the folder are set to public). Anyone else encountering this, or/and work out how to fix?

Answer (score 7):

To follow on to the questions in comments on [the answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89069/15308) from [@jaycer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/113117/jaycer) :

## How do you create a file from a template inside a specific folder

The URL would look like this

`https://docs.google.com/document/d/${temlpateId}/copy?id=${temlpateId}&copyCollaborators=false&copyComments=false&includeResolvedCommentsOnCopy=false&title=${title}&copyDestination=${folderId}&usp=docs_web`

Substituting these values :

- `${temlpateId}` : The ID of the source file/template. You can get this from the URL when you browse to the source file/template. Note that the value shows up twice in the URL
- `${title}` : The name to give the new file
- `${folderId}` : The ID of the folder to put the new file in. This comes from the URL when you browse to the Google Drive folder.

Comment: just tested this, it works. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

New Document:  `https://docs.google.com/document/create?usp=drive_web&folder=[folder-id]`

New Spreadsheet: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/create?usp=drive_web&folder=[folder-id]`

Answer (score -2):

Hmm, i just thought: actually it should be fairly easy to create a script, so that you can make a google doc by just right clicking in windows explorer. Would be insanely helpful as an alternative, if you're not using word and don't want to use the browser all the time.

Comment: I am aware this wasn't really an answer, although I don't have the reputation  to comment, that's why and I thought it might be interesting for someone ;(