# URL to create new Google doc from Template Gallery *and* set folder destination

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs-template

Right now, we have a workflow where:

1. someone goes to the Template Gallery
2. picks a template
3. saves the new doc/sheet and moves it to a specific shared Drive folder.

We're trying to reduce the number of steps.

Right now, we have a slightly easier way, where we share links that point people to the Template Gallery, and sets the default save Drive folder, like this: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/?ftv=1&folder=(folder id)&tgif=d

But then they still have to select the correct template.

We'd like to take it one step further and be able to have people bookmark a link that will effectively create a specific template that will save to a specific folder, all in one step.

I know it's related to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/106348/url-to-create-a-new-google-document-from-a-template), but that tells you how to do it by creating a "copy" vs a "Template Gallery" copy. The big difference between the two is that creating a "copy" doesn't copy any attached scripts. Our templates all have scripts. Creating a new doc via the Template Gallery preserves the scripts.

Is there a way to craft a url to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *The big difference between the two is that creating a "copy" doesn't copy any attached scripts. ... Creating a new doc via the Template Gallery preserves the scripts.*

**When creating a copy of any Google file (Doc, Sheet, etc) ALL -if any- included scripts are copied as well.**

Having said that, I believe you do not need to create a copy from a template.
Just use any simple file. Scripts will be copied as well.

Instead, try the following syntax for any file

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID_TO_COPY/copy?&copyCollaborators=false&copyComments=false&title=MY_NEW_FILE_NAME&copyDestination=FOLDER_ID_TO_SEND_TO
```

Please note that the parameters `&copyCollaborators=false` and `&copyComments=false` and `&title=MY_NEW_FILE_NAME` are optional.

So your link can be simplified to

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/FILE_ID_TO_COPY/copy?&copyDestination=FOLDER_ID_TO_SEND_TO
```

Comment: Thanks! I must've made a mistake during testing, because I tried that and discovered no script in the copy. But it works now. This is great!