# Pageless Google Doc using parameters?

Tags: google-docs, querystring

As you know, there's a **pageless** mode in Google Docs that allows you to remove the borders of a document.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/11528737

[image]

I want that because I'm embedding documents in a website, and I want them to look like regular editors. Not like:

[image]

I know I can pass parameters in the url like `?rm=minimal`. That way, I can hide the menus. And that's great. Though those parameters are not officially documented there are a few references like in here:
[All Google Docs URL parameters/functions/commands?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/130654/all-google-docs-url-parameters-functions-commands)

But do you know if `pageless` is available as a url param? I tried things like `?pageless`, `?pageless=true`, `?page=pageless`, `?setup=pageless` with no luck.

So, any clue on how to enable *pageless* without opening the menu manually? I want to automate this.

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. It's the 6th time.  "Any clue looks..." looks to me to be too broad. What are looking as an answer? Are you open to using web browser dev tools? I.E. to learn how to analyze the client-server communication of a web app to find how the turn on/off of the feature is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Since turning on the pageless mode doesn't add a querystring / parameter it's very likely that there isn't a parameter to control this feature. I think that the query string aren't used for controlling new features with very few exceptions like the Google Sheets filter views and those that still works nowadays are kept to not annoy people that use them.

The [Google Apps Script Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases) doesn't mention this feature so it's very likely that it's not officially supported yet.

You might find helpful to learn how to use the autocomplete feature of the Google Apps Script editor and to use JavaScript stuff to scan the Documents Service (DocumentApp) to look for methods, enum, objects and properties for undocumented stuff. This "technique" helped to find properties of event object from another Google Apps Script service, more specifically  `rowStart`, `rowEnd`, `columnStart` and `columnEnd` from the Google Apps Script edit event object.

Another thing that you might do is to post a feature request on the Google Apps Script Issue Tracker. For details see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support.

One more thing that you might do is to learn how to analyse the Google Docs network activity i.e. by using Google Chrome Developers Tools. For details see https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/