# How to copy a Google Doc URL with human-readable title?

Tags: google-docs

I'd like to copy a link to a Google doc and paste it in a note-taking app. I'd like the URL link to contain the doc title instead than a seemingly random sequence of characters and digits, so when I check the note again in e.g. a few months, I can understand what the link is about without having to click on it. Is there a way to do that?

For example I would like to copy and paste the following human-readable URL:

`https://docs.google.com/document/[some short and possibly non-human-readable id here to make the url unique]/recurrent-subscriptions`

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in feature for that. If your note taking app doesn't allow to use links meaning showing a text instead of the URL, or it does but you still want someting on the URL that reminds you the doc title, try using a custom field and value on the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) or [URI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) (usually referred as hash), i.e.

https://example.com?title=some_fancy_title

https://example.com#some_fancy_title

If the Google Doc URL already have a `?` or `#` don't add a second time any of these characters.

Related

- [All Google Docs URL parameters/functions/commands?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/130654/88163)