# Bookmark / shortcut URL to create a new Google Drive doc

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is it possible to create a URL that will open a new Google Drive document, so that I can save as a bookmark and then will have essentially a short cut my bookmarks bar to be able to open a new doc?

Comment: [This answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/150644/117311) which shows how to build a **custom shortcut for creating a new file** may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - this is the URL you need:    https://docs.google.com/document/create

Comment: More examples here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26304/url-to-create-a-new-google-document

Answer (score 2):

[There is now](https://twitter.com/googledocs/status/1055490445088903168) a fancy new way: the `.new` [gTLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain).

Per [QZ](https://qz.com/work/1441913/a-new-trick-for-starting-google-docs-slides-sheets-and-forms/), all these URLs now work:

- Docs: doc.new, docs.new, document.new
- Forms: form.new, forms.new
- Sheets: sheet.new, sheets.new, spreadsheet.new
- Sites: site.new, sites.new, website.new
- Slides: slides.new, deck.new, presentation.new

Comment: slide.new also works for Slides