# How to create shortcut for new Google Doc with for secondary logged in user?

Tags: google-docs, google-account

I'm logged into my browser with two different Gmail accounts, one is personal and the other is my work account.

I have created shortcuts for Google Calendar, Google Cloud Platform, etc. as following:

- https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/1/r
- https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list?authuser=1

Notice the `1` keyword here in the URLs, it tells Google to use my alternate cookie but the same tricks are not working for quickly creating a Google Doc.

I find it really hard to navigate through 3 different clicks and load time for quickly jotting down stuff while discussing with my colleagues in remote environment.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "quickly create a Goole doc"? Have you considered to use different browsers, one for each account or using different browser profiles one for each account? What web browser are you using?

Comment: No given all the plugin, bookmarks and other setup on the Chrome I would like to stick with the same for both the accounts. By "quickly create a Goole doc" I mean is the ability to define a shortcut for creating a new google doc from the desired account, be it either a bookmark or javascript anything.
Fact that I am already able to do the same for other Google products like GCP, Calendar, Gmail, etc. I want to get the same done for Google Docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/create`

Related

- [Can I form a direct URL to a particular Gmail account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/18959/88163)
- [URL to create a new Google document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26304/88163)
- [Google multiple accounts - In URL selection by email instead of by user number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40280661/1595451)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/u/1/create actually helped me. Thanks a lot!